# I am getting [object object] but I want to make a checkmark button prepended to the "value" variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am playing around with making a list and I got everything prepended onto HTML but now am trying to remove them by hitting a button.  What I am having issue with is prepending the button.  I am confident I can remove it with logic that is not included in this snippit but any help on how to create the button would be appreciated.

```
window.onload = function() {
//user clicked on the add button in the to-do field add that text into the to-do text
$('#add-to-do').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //assign variable to the value entered into the textbox
    var value = document.getElementById('to-do').value;  
    //test value
    console.log(value);
    //prepend values into the html and add checkmark, checkbox, and line break to make list
    var linebreak = "<br/>";
    var todoclose = $("<button>");

    console.log(todoclose);
    todoclose.attr("data-to-do", toDoCount);
    todoclose.addClass("checkbox");
    todoclose.text("☑");

    $("#to-dos").prepend(todoclose + value + linebreak);


});
```

Below is the HTML

```
                <div class ="col-4">
                <!-- To Do List -->
                <form onsubmit= "return false;">
                    <span id = "todo-item" type = "text">
                    <h4>Add your Agenda Here</h4>
                    <input id ="to-do" type = "text">
                    <input id ="add-to-do" value = "Add Item" type = "submit">
                    </span>
                </form>
             <div id="to-dos"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
todoclose + value + linebreak
```

`todoclose` is an Object, `value` is a string, and `linebreak` is a string. That means that in the first part of that code, you are adding an Object (`todoclose`) with a string (`value`).

When you add an Object to a string, the JavaScript engine calls the object's `toString` method to convert it to a string first, and then adds the result to the other string. The `toString` method on most objects prints `[object Object]` (which isn't very useful).

To fix it, instead of using `+` to add these together, you can prepend them one at a time (in reverse order):

```
$("#to-dos").prepend(linebreak);
$("#to-dos").prepend(value);
$("#to-dos").prepend(todoclose);
```